# how to convert date into int in c#?

Tags: c#

i try too much and spend time from over the internet to search how to converting date to integer by using c# but i didn't get good answer i trying so much thing to do it but it was not working as well like this

```
int aa = 0;
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr;
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select dat from T0");
            cmd.Connection = con;

            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                aa = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString());
            }
            MessageBox.Show(aa.ToString());

            con.Close();
```

please anybody have an solution for this thing !!!

regards Dlovan

Comment: What do you mean by _not working_? You get any exception or error message? What is the type of `dat` column? What do you except as an integer result from your `dat` value?

Comment: @CharlesMager There is only one format! The Unix one! 1 Jan 1970 is enough for everybody :-) And milliseconds everywhere!

Comment: `DateTime.Date.GetHashCode()` ??

Comment: @ Soner Gönül 

dat means is the field from database i entered the date , e.x : 25/5/2015

my error is says "input string is not correct format"

Comment: @DlovanBakhtiar Then what kind of result you except when you parse your `25/5/2015` to integer? **EDIT**: Okey I give up..

Comment: @Soner Gönül it says "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: @DlovanBakhtiar
What does `dr[0].GetType().FullName` returns?

Comment: What is the output of     `dr[0].ToString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that dr[0] is DateTime:

```
long aa = Convert.ToInt64(((DateTime)dr[0]).ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")); //int isn't enough
```

if you need only yyyyMMdd you can:

```
int aa = Convert.ToInt32(((DateTime)dr[0]).ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
```

Comment: @SonerGönül I think that my error is the "as DateTime" because it isn't nullable(I'm going to correct this), but I'm not assigning string to long, I'm doing Convert.ToInt64

Comment: Won't work my friend it has error from there \((dr[0] as DateTime)

Comment: @Specified it has errror says " cast is not valid. "

Answer (score 0):

It depends with how much precision do u want the `DateTime` to be.

If you need absolute precision use `Int64 (long)`, over `Ticks`.

If u insist on using `Int32 (int)` try something like `epoch time [Total seconds since 1, Jan 1970]`

```
var int = (myDateTime - new DateTime(1, 1, 1970)).TotalSeconds;
```

Comment: your answer is static date i wanted to get from database

Comment: @parimal `TotalSeconds` is `double`

Answer (score 0):

Convert your DateTime to ticks.

```
var ticks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
var date = new DateTime (ticks);
```

Comment: your answer is static date i wanted to get from database

Comment: It doesn't matter. You can use any DateTime value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
string strDate = dr[0].ToString(); // 25/05/2015
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
int inst = Convert.ToInt32((dt - new DateTime(1970, 01, 01)).TotalSeconds);
```

Comment: it has error says "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: date format must be - "dd/MM/yyyy". check is your date format same, otherwise change as per. as your date is "25/5/2015" then change format for "dd/M/yyyy" and then check this

Comment: @ Bhupesh Mhashakhetri i doing this